# Etymology of “the fix is in”

Tags: etymology, idioms

The common phrase “the fix is in” means that the outcome of an event or process has been covertly manipulated to ensure a result that would otherwise be determined by chance or a fair test of some kind.

What is the origin of this phrase?

**Note:** I'm interested specifically in the origin of the entire phrase, not in the etymology of the word “fix” as used within it.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be that "fix" is perfectly understandable.  It's almost just a "common phrase" - not an idiom.  If you check "idiom" in the dictionary, an idiom is specifically when the meaning is **not deducible** from the meaning of the words.  So, "over the moon" ("happy") is utterly meaningless unless you know it is an idiom. But if you "fix" the outcome of a fight, that seems to be descriptive, not idiomatic??

Comment: I'm referring specifically to the phrase as a whole, not the use of the word “fix,” which by itself is not an idiom, as you say—but to say “the fix is in,” rather than *e.g.* “the outcome's been fixed,” seems idiomatic to me.

Comment: Hi Will, I guess I see what you mean ... anyway the point here is to find the origin!

Comment: Is it really a common phrase? I'd never heard or read it before today.

Comment: Hi Will.  It's an absolutely common phrase in English.  All native speakers would know it.

Comment: I am a native speaker, and as I said I had never heard it. But I'll take your word for it that it's common.

Comment: **A fix** and **to be in** are two **separate phrases**: Not a single one. And there is nothing about covert in either of them. "to be in" is used in retail shops/business **to signal a new arrival**: Our summer swimsuits **are in**. The fix is in, in that sense, is: The solution to some problem (the fix) is now available to people.

Comment: It is not a common phrase and the meaning given sounds really off to my native ears.

Answer (score 3):

[Fix](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fix) used in the sense you are referring to dates back to the 18th century:

> - Sense of "tamper with" (a fight, a jury, etc.) is from 1790.

probably from the earlier meaning :

> - "settle, assign" evolved into "adjust, arrange" (1660s), then "repair".

(Etymonline)

Ad a set phrase the earliest   usage I could find is from the '40s, but earlier usages are possible:

From: [Collier's, Volume 106 Crowell-Collier Publishing Company, 1940](https://books.google.it/books?id=5SEfAQAAMAAJ&q=%22fix%20is%20in%22&dq=%22fix%20is%20in%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAmoVChMIkKGujNjMxwIVaZ3bCh0D8wS2)

> - ... fifteen dollars on a fight in his life. "Well, here it is," the McCoy tough guy explained. "We're from New York and you're from New York and we seen you're okay. So we're out here for the fight. On business. ***The fix is in and the white boy wins.***

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fix%20is%20in&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfix%20is%20in%3B%2Cc0): *fix is in*.

Comment: It is used in the sense of 'fix a crime on someone' in 1728 (Ainsworth's Dictionary) but I cannot tell from the context if that means 'nail the culprit', or 'stick the blame on'.

Comment: BTW I'm so gladdened to see an apostrophe used correctly on '40s here, meaning you omitted the "19". (However it seems to be superfluous, as the plural "forties" has as much information as the plural "nineteen forties".)

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the expression can be found in Bernard Malamud's "The Natural," p. 203 (Farrar, Straus & Giroux, 1952), "The fix is on." The speaker is a not-especially educated man, so the variation is probably deliberate on Malamud's part.

Answer (score 1):

J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994) reports that *fix* as a noun in sporting slang dates to at least 1898, and as a noun in underworld term meaning "the amount needed to secure bribed cooperation" dates to at least 1946:

> **fix** *n.* **1.a.** *Sports*. a contest having an illicitly prearranged outcome. [First two cited examples:] **1898** *Sat Eve. Post* (July 30) 70: As I said before, it was as clear a case of "fix" as if she had given {the runner} a drug. **1947** Schulberg *Harder They Fall* 246: A fight fix. ... **b.** *Und.* the amount needed to secure bribed cooperation [First cited example:] **1946** Dadswell *Hey, Sucker* 38: Yet if the "fix" is high the concessionaires are forced to make the public pay the bill.

Hyman Goldin, *Dictionary of American Underworld Lingo* (1950) has this entry for *fix* as a noun:

> **Fix**, *n.* **1.** An agreement, secured through bribery, chicanery, intimidation, whereby a criminal indictment is quashed, or the severity of a sentence or of a charge lessened. "**The fix is in**. Don't take no plea (plead guilty to a lesser offense). The worst you'll score for (get) is a draw (suspended sentence)." **2.** Any arrangement by which laws, rules, or regulations are circumvented; or by which penalties are evaded; the *alzo* [setup agreement to avoid conflict with rivals or police interference]. "Mickey Mouse from uptown and his mob got a license (police permission) to hustle (steal) on the cannon (picking pockets) here. **The fix is in** solid.

One early newspaper article that uses the expression "the fix was in" is "[Crime an Industry: Criminal Who Owns Judges and Police: Gross Income of His Gang £21,000,000 a Year](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/71175095?searchTerm=%22fix+was+in%22)," in the *[Queensland] Worker* (January 28, 1931), quoting at length from Fred Pasley, *Al Capone: The Biography of a Self-Made Man* (1930):

> Capone learned slowly, and was charged with carrying weapons and threatening a humble taxi-driver. But he has already established what Chicago calls the "hookup"—the alliance of crime with the law.
>
> "He did not even appear in Court. The charges were mysteriously dropped, expunged from the record. **The fix was in**. The political hook-up was functioning.
>
> "The hook-up. The story begins and ends with it. The red thread of the Capone career is strung on it. Back of the machine and sawed-off shot-gun crews, nerving the arm of the assassin and the thug; riding at the wheel of every death car; exploiting crime and its spoils—the hook-up."

A slightly later instance, this time from a sporting context (prizefighting) appears in Bill Corum, "[The 12 Hours Before the Bell](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=8BHnAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22was+the+theme+song+of+1932%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22The+12+Hours%22),"  unidentified article in *Hearst's International Combined with Cosmopolitan* (August 1932) [snippet view]:

> Facing the prospect of meeting a Jack Johnson who had sent him a last-minute warning that he was going to do his best, after it had been mutually understood that **"the fix" was in**, James J. Jeffries went off into the woods alone and came back a broken, beaten man on the eve of Reno's first front-page battle.

Not surprisingly, Maurice Weseen, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1930) includes entries for *fix* (as a verb) as an underworld term and "fixed fight" as a sports term:

> **Fix—**To bribe.
>
> **Fixed fight—**A prizefight in which the outcome is arranged in advance.

So whether "the fix is in" originated among gangsters or among sports aficionados, it has clearly been in use for at least ninety years.

---

***Conclusions***

My sense is that *fix*, as used in the expression "the fix is in" refers to "setting something aright" or "correcting a problem" (as seen from the point of view of the person who is arranging the fix). Indeed, *fix* used as a verb in an allied sense goes back to the eighteenth century, according to Lighter:

> **fix** *v.* **1.** *Pol. & Und.* to secure the cooperation of (someone) through the payment of a bribe [First five cited examples:] **1790** in [Mitford Mathews, *Dictionary of Americanisms* (1950)]: It is expected of us that we should fix the Governor of Pennsylvania. **1872** Burnham *Secret Service* 72: When Biebusch saw *this* man in Court, whom he fancied he had "fixed" for certain, the criminal wilted. **1872** Crapsey *Nether Side* 58: He had "fixed" the clerk at the lace shawl counter. **1890** Quinn *Fools of Fortune* 353: We found it convenient to have recourse to the scales of a Junk dealer who had been previously "fixed" for the occasion. **1902** Hapgood *Thief* 81 {ref. to *ca*1885} The reliable attorney got a bondman, and two friends of his "fixed" the cops, who made no complaints.

The trajectory of usage seems to have been first *fix* as a verb meaning to bribe a politician, then as a verb meaning to bribe accomplices or police officers, then as a noun in sports lingo to refer to a dishonestly contested sporting event whose result was settled in advance through payment of a bribe, then as a noun in underworld slang referring to a judicial proceeding similarly predetermined, and finally as part of the longer expression "the fix is in" either in a sporting or underworld sense (or in both simultaneously) as a way of announcing or describing such an arrangement.

Comment: to be in comes from selling and retailing. If someone "is in", the shop or store has received it and can then sell to to the public. POr, it can also be used where opinions need to be handed in, in writing. No one seemed to address this point at all. Also, the question is not a "set expression" at all.....